# How to echo gravity forms entry count in a wordpress theme template

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity

I'm using the [gravity forms wordpress plugin](http://www.gravityforms.com/).

And I am trying to echo the entry count on form #1 - in my wordpress theme files.

I can't seem to find anything on how to do this - does anyone know a filter/action I can add to my functions to do this?

Really appreciate any ideas, thank you!

Comment: i think you had purchased the plugin. So you will get a premium support at [Gravity forms forum](http://www.gravityhelp.com/forums/)

Comment: @libin - yeah their support is awesome!!! but my 2 year premium support run out a couple of weeks ago :(

Answer (score 4):

Here are two methods.

Method 1 - Writing your own SQL Query

```
function get_entry_count($formid)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $count = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM wp_rg_lead WHERE form_id=$formid" );
    return $count[0]->count;
}

echo get_entry_count(1);
```

Method 2 - Using GravityForms Built in function.

```
$formid = 1;
$form_count = RGFormsModel::get_form_counts($formid);
// Displaying Total Entries
echo $form_count['total'];
```

Comment: This is soo useful thank you! But I will test it in the next week and get back to. So many times I needed this answer! Thanks

Comment: @Joshc were you able to successfully test this out?

Comment: Hi @Erisu, great answer... What if I have the same form for several posts and I set a hidden field to store the post id for which the form was submitted on? Can you have this echo for that form ID AND post ID? Thanks!

Comment: @Jaypee, Yes, it is possible with method one.  You will need to update the function parameters and query.

Function parameters will need the field number in which is the hidden form field that contains the post id and the post id we are matching against.  The query will check against the lead detail table instead of the lead table.  The lead detail table contains the data for each form field.  Sample Query: `SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE form_id=$formId AND (field_number=$postFieldNumber AND value=$postId)`